# how to call element in static void?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a little selenium program with c#. I want to wait max 5 seconds to interact button or something if its visible. I've made a code for it but I cannot call that code inside static void main it says an object is required non-static field. how do I fix this ?
an error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By, int)

class Program
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mail.com/int/");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-button"));
        login.Click();
        IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-email"));
        waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By.Id("login-email"), 5);
        email.SendKeys("CarlosdanielGrossen95@mail.com");


    }


        public  IWebElement waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By locator,int maxseconds)
    {


       return new  WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxseconds))
            .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((locator)));
    }

}
}
```

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By, int)

Comment: You need make `waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible` methods static.

Comment: this time "driver" says it cannot be inside static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method static.

```cs
        public static IWebElement waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By locator,int maxseconds)
    {


       return new  WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxseconds))
            .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((locator)));
    }
```

Comment: the driver word is red this time, the one after WebDriverWait(
error: An Object Reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.driver'

Comment: @UmutPınarbaşı Same thing, make `driver` static this time. And read up on static and non-static members while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

Define this method in a separate class and call this method with PageWait Object.

```
public class PageWait
{
  public  IWebElement waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By locator,int maxseconds)
    {
       return new  WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxseconds))
            .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists((locator)));
    }
}

class Program { 
public IWebDriver driver;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.mail.com/int/");
        IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-button"));
        login.Click();
        IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-email"));
        new PageWait().waitForPageUntilElementIsVisible(By.Id("login-email"), 5);
        email.SendKeys("CarlosdanielGrossen95@mail.com");

    }
}
```